# Revolution plot with missing pieces

Tags: plotting

I have the following $1D$ bump function `h1` defined as follows:

```
h[t_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[1/(t^2 - 1)], -1 < t < 1}, {0, Abs[t] >= 1}}];
h1[t_] := Exp[1] Piecewise[{{h[(t + a)/(b - a)], -b < t < -a}, {h[(t - a)/(b - a)], a < t < b}, {0, Abs[t] >= b}, {Exp[1/(-1)], -a <= t <= a}}];
```

The graph is, for `a=1,b=3`:
[image]

To turn this into a $2D$ bump function and make a plot I tried two solutions:

- using a substitution $t\mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and then using `Plot3D`
- using `RevolutionPlot3D[h1[t], {t, -4, 4}]`

In both cases I get an irregular plot with two rings missing:

[image]

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Great, this solves the missing rings. I got that MaxRecursion and PlotPoints do the rest. Thank you.